# Dropdown menu on sticky menu?

Tags: html, css

First of all I am newbie in all of this, started to learn coding a week ago. I have little problem with my navbar. I want to put dropdown menu in sticky navbar. here's [a link](http://www.umas.hr/%7Efbalta/test/TEST/webweb.html) to html file. I want to put dropdown menus under these menu1, menu2...

Also I would like to set width of nav bar same as width of content if it's possible. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you put your CSS & HTML code

Comment: Please do not rely on external links for your code.  Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://www.umas.unist.hr/~fbalta/test/TEST/)  you can find both the html and css code. :)

Comment: @MalaLadno Please put the code in your post. We should not have to go off set, let alone download files.

Comment: Check out my code, hope it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

In order to add drop down menu to your navbar you simply need to use the "select" tags and inside the "select" tags you will use the "option" tags where you will insert your options of the drop down menu

```
<select>
       <option>None</option>
       <option>Mr.</option>
       <option>Mrs.</option>
       <option>Miss.</option>       
</select>
```

And then if you want to set the width of the nav bar then you will need
to insert the nav bar inside "Div" tags. You will then assign an id to 
the the div tags.

```
<div id="navbar">
</div>
```

And then you can use the above assigned div id in CSS file to adjust the width
of the above div accrodingly

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/px0bt26o/4/

Hello there! here's what you are looking to do

HTML:

```
     <div class="header">
        <h2>fb</h2>

      </div>
            <div id="navbar">
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">MENU1 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Some Text here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Whatever you want</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello &amp; There</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU2 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Text Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Text Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Text Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello &amp; Menu2</a></li>
                </ul>


            </li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>

      <div class="content">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum Bipsum Dipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem torem borem dorem jorem sorem.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Marat Sans;
  src: url(fonts/MaratSans.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Marat Sans;
  src: url(fonts/MaratSansthin.otf);
  font-weight: thin;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Noe Display;
  src: url(fonts/NoeDisplayMedium.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Charter;
  src: url(fonts/charter.otf);
}

h3 {

  font-family: Marat Sans;
  font-size: 40px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: charter; 
     background: #fff;

  }

  .header {
    background-color: #f1f1f100;
    margin top: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    font-size: 24px;
font-family: Noe Display;
  }

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
        font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Marat Sans;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#17a67c;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
    width: 160%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
 .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background:#fff;
  }

  .sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
```